# Tensorflow Insert Operation Between Operations

Tags: tensorflow

If I have the following tensorflow graph constructed like

```
a = tf.Variable(0.8, name='a')
b = tf.Variable(0.6, name='b')
c = tf.Variable(0.4, name='c')
ab = tf.mul(a, b, name='mul_ab')
abc = tf.mul(ab, c, name='mul_abc')
```

Is there any way to insert an operation between mul_ab and mul_abc after executing these five lines? For example, inserting a conditional between mul_ab and mul_abc would be equivalent to the graph generated by

```
a = tf.Variable(0.8, name='a')
b = tf.Variable(0.6, name='b')
c = tf.Variable(0.4, name='c')
ab = tf.cond(a < tf.constant(1.0),                 # Arbitrary comparison
             lambda: tf.zeros(1),                  # Arbitrary return value
             lambda: tf.mul(a, b, name='mul_ab'))  # Original return value
abc = tf.mul(ab, c, name='mul_abc')
```

Comment: You could try out `contrib/graph_editor`

Comment: Yes, I think something like the graph_editor contrib library may be your best bet. In general --- you can convert a Tensorflow graph to a GraphDef protocol buffer, transform that protocol buffer, and then convert back it into a graph. However, it won't be trivial to do without some helper libraries.

Comment: Awesome, can't believe I missed this. This seem exactly what I need. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Are there any usage examples for contrib/graph_editor? I can't seem to find much online, and the docs are a bit hard to parse.